# Modifier.scrollable doesn't scroll the content

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to have a layout where the content should be scrollable. But it doesn't work. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val offset = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        Column(                                      // This should be scrollable
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .scrollable(
                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                    state = rememberScrollableState { delta ->
                        offset.value = offset.value + delta
                        delta
                    }
                )
        ) {
            Text(...)
            Text(...)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            LazyColumn(...)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            DropdwonMenu(...)
            Text(...)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            Text(...)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            Column(...)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            Button(...)
        }
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        ) {
            Error(snackbarHostState)
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(state.error) {
        if (state.error.isNotEmpty()) {
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(state.error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace `scrollable` with `.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())`. Your code is updating `offset` but this value is not actually being used anywhere to offset content. `scrollable` is useful if you need fine control over scrolling. But it appears in your case that you don't need it and verticalScroll will do the job.